# Mail Settings are disabled

Tags: email

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607) to set my email app to open Gmail in my browser.

But the Settings are disabled (see screenshot).

How can I set my email app to Gmail?[image]

Comment: That modal dialog looks more like the one to set up a new mail account, rather than define a default app. I don't have Ventura to check against.

Comment: @Tetsujin, anytime I open the Mail app, that dialog pops up. But I'm not interacting with the model, just the Mail > Settings menu.

Comment: That would seem to equate with the last para of your link… "You might be asked to add an email account before you can change the setting in Mail. If you don't want to do that, open the other email app and check its settings for a similar way to set the default email reader. "

Comment: There's a prefs plugin that could be used to set defaults - [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) idk if it's still good for Ventura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link:

> You might be asked to add an email account before you can change the setting in Mail. If you don't want to do that, open the other email app and check its settings for a similar way to set the default email reader.

If your desired email client does not have functionality to set the default client, you can temporarily add an email account that doesn't need to exist to be able to access Mail settings.

1. Choose to add ‘Other Mail Account’.
2. Set email address to `a@localhost` and enter any password.
3. Click Sign In and wait for it to fail verification.
4. Enter `localhost` in all fields and click Sign In again, waiting for it to fail verification.
5. Click Next to proceed without passing verification.

You can now access Mail preferences to set your desired email client.

The fake Mail account can be removed from Mail → Accounts once complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to get to GMail.

1. Use a web browser to go to the website `https://GMail.com`  The link you used tells how to change which browser you use, but has nothing to do with what website you go to.
2. What you are apparently trying to do is have Mail.app go to Gmail.  In the screenshot you provided, the next step is to click on the colorful "Google," then click the "Continue" button, then login to Gmail.  Hopefully, it will be easy to understand after that.  I don't use Gmail, so I can't take you further.